# MongoDB query on a subarray

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have the following document

```
{
   "_id" : "someId",
   "name" : "myTeam",
   "team" : [
                {
                    "entity" : "size",
                    "value" : 14
                },
                {
                    "entity" : "returns",
                    "value" : 45
                }
            ]
}
```

I need to retrieve all the teams that have a value of size > 10. How could I achieve that in mongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
db.collection.find( { team: 
                         { $elemMatch: 
                              { value: 
                                  { $gt: 10 },
                                  entity: 'size'
                              } 
                         }
                      }
                  )
```

Comment: hey, sorry for sounding stupid, but if I provide an id here, I would just receive that one document, how do I fetch all the teams with size greater than 10. I tried to remove the first JSON but it gave me an error

Comment: Yes .. sorry, there is one missing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You query the array subdocuments directly:

```
db.collection.find({ "team.value" : { $gt : 10 } });
```

Comment: So how do you know whether the value is for size or returns?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for you:

`db.collection.find({ "team.value" : { $gt : 10 }, "team.entity": "size" });`